# Splitting a file in two at the first occurrence of an specified string

Tags: text-processing

How can I split a text file in two parts at the first occurrence of a specified string? I looked at the split command, but it doesn't do that.

In the past I have used a script to do this. But it is not very efficient, and I have to move the script to different systems. I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I recommend the use of  *csplit* (context split), a la:

*csplit [options] file PATTERN*

For example, let's take a file **filename** containing

```
one
two 
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
```

with the command *csplit filename /four/*

we get file **xx00** with

```
one
two 
three
```

and file **xx01** with

```
four
five
six
seven
eight
```

More detail can be found at http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch35_10.htm and also at https://davidlyness.com/post/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities